# Asymptotic solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

I have asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838619/435814) question on math.stackexchange, however, have not got any answer. Therefore, I suspect that this system of ordinary differential equations cannot be solved analytically. But I still have some hope that it is possible to show that $a(u)\sim -1/u$ for $u\rightarrow \infty$. The system arises in physics, approximate treatment of the Hubbard model using some newly developed formalism.

$$2 a'(u)=u x'(u),$$
$$4 a u x'(u)-4 y'(u)=-2 x(u) \big[u a'(u)+a(u)\big],$$
$$4 a u y'(u)-4 x'(u)=\big[u\lambda'(a)a'(u)+\lambda(a)\big]-2y(u)\big[u a'(u)+a(u)\big].$$
with initial conditions
$$x(0)=y(0)=0, a(0)=-1/2,$$
and $\lambda(a)=a^3+\frac14 a$.

It is easy to find a series solution in the vicinity of $u=0$. It is also possible to integrate one of the equations. But the problem is in the infinity point $u\rightarrow \infty$.

To my astonishment, a simpler approximation results in a system of 2 ODEs of similar structure, which indeed permits [analytic solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4837871/435814).

*Edit*

In the meantime I managed to integrate 2 equations out of 3 and got:
$$
y(u)=\frac{1}{2} u a(u) x(u)+\frac{a(u)^2}{2}-\frac{1}{8},\\
2 \Lambda (a(u))-u x(u) \lambda (a(u))+4 u a(u) x(u) y(u)-2 \left(x(u)^2+y(u)^2\right)=\frac{3}{32},
$$
where $\Lambda (a)=\frac{1}{8} a^2 \left(2 a^2+1\right)$. But I still do not know how to get asymptotics. The remaining equations are
$$
2 a'(u)=u x'(u),\\
4 a(u)^2 \left(3 u^2 x(u)^2+1\right)=4 x(u) \big(u a(u)+4 x(u)\big)+1.
$$

Comment: Numerically, the large-$u$ behavior is given by 
$a(u)=
-1.02418609585 u^{-1}
+0.56465348534 u^{-3}
+1.36082946003 u^{-5}
+0.94254923789 u^{-7}
$,
$x(u)=
0.34089869589
-1.02418609585 u^{-2}
+0.84698022802 u^{-4}
+2.26804910005 u^{-6}
$,
$y(u)=
-0.2995718522
+1.1452019773 u^{-2}
-1.0692455654 u^{-4}
-2.6928672430 u^{-6}
$ for your initial conditions. (Mathematica, high-precision NDSolve, expansion around $u=\infty$)

Comment: @FredHucht Yes, this is quite plausible.

Comment: @FredHucht Why not posting your solution? At first I was convinced that $a(u)=-1/u +\ldots$ and that deviation in the leading  coefficient of your solution is just a numerical noise. But I am more convinced now that it is real.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the numerics are correct. The leading term -1.024... varies continuously with $a(0)$. I do not find a better way to handle your ODE system. One could use your edit and write down one single ODE, but this is highly nonlinear. Maybe I play around with it today, then I'll write an answer.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462501, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296527

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my comment as an answer.
Using Mathematica's ParametricNDSolve[] with 50 digits precision as well as a series expansion around $u=\infty$, I get
\begin{align}
a(u) &= -1.02418609585 u^{-1} + 0.56465348534 u^{-3} + O(u^{-5}) \\
x(u) &=  0.34089869589 - 1.02418609585 u^{-2} + O(u^{-4}) \\
y(u) &= -0.2995718522 + 1.1452019773 u^{-2} + O(u^{-4})
\end{align}
for the given initial condition $a_0=a(0)=-1/2$.
Therefore, the leading term $a_\infty=\lim_{u\to\infty} u\,a(u)$ is $a_\infty=-1.024\ldots \neq -1$.
We can however ask the inverse question, namely for which $a_0^*$ we get $a_\infty=-1$, with result $a_0^*=-0.92708111527$.

Interestingly, the Taylor series of $a(u)$ around $u=\infty$ contains a lot of terms proportional to $\sqrt{a_\infty^2-1}$, and significantly simplifies for $a_\infty=-1$.
As example, the $u^{-3}$ term reads
$$
\frac{a_{\infty } (4-3 a_{\infty }^2) }{3 a_{\infty }^2+1} \left(3 a_{\infty } \sqrt{a_{\infty }^2-1}-2\right)\stackrel{a_\infty=-1}{\mapsto} \frac 1 2 \,.
$$
Therefore, the limit $a_\infty=-1$ seems to be a special case.

Similarly, the expansion around $u=0$ contains terms proportional to $\sqrt{4a_0^2-1}$, which drop out for $a_0=-1/2$.

Comment: Thank you, very useful! In other words, the $u^{-1}$ coefficient can only be obtained numerically and is different from $-1$. On the other hand, all other coefficients of the series expansion can be written in terms of it.

Comment: Yes, and it depends on $a_0$ (assuming $x(0)=y(0)=0$). Maybe, $a_\infty=-1$ holds if you slightly change the ODE and especially $\lambda(a)$.