# One solution is known, how to find another one

Tags: differential-equations

This question is driven by pure curiosity as for all practical purposes I can generate numerical or series solutions of the given ODE
\begin{align}
p(a,u) [a'(u)]^2+q(a,u)a'(u)+a(u) &= 0,\\
a(0) &= -1/2.
\end{align}
Here $p, q, r$ are complicated polynomials of $a$ and $u$ given at the bottom of my post, and it should be noted that this equation was derived by integrating 2 out of 3 ODEs in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461866/41145), which have much simpler form).

What really interests me is whether it is possible to find one solution ($a_1$) in algebraic form given the fact that the second solution ($a_2$) is known as a degree-12 curve. The solutions can be identified by their series expansions in the vicinity of $u=0$ and at $u\rightarrow\infty$:
\begin{align}
a_1(u)&=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{u^2}{64}+\frac{9 u^4}{4096}+\frac{9 u^6}{131072}+\mathcal{O}(u^8),&a_1(u)&=-\frac{1.024}{u}+\mathcal{O}(u^{-3}),\\
a_2(u)&=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{u^2}{64}+\frac{9 u^4}{4096}+\frac{17 u^6}{131072}+\mathcal{O}(u^8)&
a_2(u)&=-\frac{1}{u}+\mathcal{O}(u^{-3}),
\end{align}
where one asymptotic solution was found in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462144/41145).
As the numerical solution reveals, $a_1(u)$ and $a_2(u)$ are very similar.
[image]

It's impressive that $a_2(u)$ can be [found analytically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296575/9469) from the simple condition:
\begin{align}
q(a,u)^2-4p(a,u)r(a,u)&=0,&\Rightarrow a_2(u)&=-\frac{\sqrt{u^2-\sqrt{u^4-4 u^2+16}+4}}{\sqrt{6} u}.
\end{align}
I have no idea why it works this way. It would be really great if someone could shed light on it. But the main question is whether $a_1$ has a simple algebraic form.

Finally, I present the explicit expressions for the $p, q$, and $r$ polynomials:
\begin{align}
p(a, u)&=3 a^2 u^2 \left(36 a^4 u^4+3 a^2 \left(u^2-48\right) u^2-u^4+8 u^2+192\right)-\left(u^2+16\right)^2,\\
q(a, u)&=2 a u \left(9 a^4 u^4-3 a^2 \left(u^2-4\right) u^2-\left(u^2+16\right)\right),\\
r(a, u)&=a^2 u^2 \left(3 a^2 \left(3 a^2-1\right) u^2-1\right),
\end{align}
and apologize for the long post.